# Is $Ape_1+Aqe_2$ where A (3x3) matrix, considered as a linear combination of $e_1,e_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

---

$$\alpha=-8$$

---

Eigenvectors:

$$e_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \text{ and }
e_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

---

What  I did :

**(i)**

$x ∈ V \implies x$ of the form $pe_1 + qe_2$

$$Ax = A(pe_1 + qe_2) = p(Ae_1) + q(Ae_2)=Ap (e_1) + Aq (e_2)$$

**This raised a question**

---

Over here:

$$Ap (e_1) + Ap (e_2)$$

$Ap$ and $Aq$ aren't **numbers** , they are matrices, so it is valid to say that $Ax$ contains a linear combination of $e_1,e_2$ ?

Are matrices treated as numbers over here?

---

This Thought has disturbed My Proof, please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "A and M are matrices, considered as a linear combination of $e_1,e_2$"?  What is it that we know about the matrix $A$?  Do we know what its columns are?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom A is a 3x3 matrix :)

Comment: Do $e_1$ and $e_2$ denote the standard basis vectors?  Also, for future reference, any important information that you put in the title should be repeated in the body of the question.  Your title should just be a quick summary of the question that you have.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom , Im so sorry. Fixed my whole question :) Take a look :)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom , the question has not mentioned if it's the standard basis vectors.

Comment: Why don't you simply copy the question, exactly as it is written? The fact that we have eigenvectors *does* change a lot about the question.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom , done :) Im so sorry :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's talk about this question:

> Let $A$ denote some $n \times n$ matrix.  Let $e_1,e_2$ denote two eigenvectors of $A$.
>   Let $V$ denote the linear space spanned by $e_1$ and $e_2$.
>
> Prove that, for any vector $x$ belonging to $V$, the vector $Ax$ also belongs to V.

I would prove the above as follows: note that $e_1,e_2$ are eigenvectors.  By the definition of an eigenvector, this means that there exist two scalars ("numbers", not matrices) $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ such that
$$
A e_1 = \lambda_1 e_1, \quad A e_2 = \lambda_2 e_2
$$
We may write any element $x \in V$ in the form $x = a_1 e_1 + a_2 e_2$ (where $a_1,a_2$ are numbers, not vectors).  We note that for any such element $x$, we have
$$
Ax = A(a_1 e_1 + a_2 e_2) = a_1 A e_1 + a_2 A e_2 = a_1 \lambda_1 e_1 + a_2 \lambda_2 e_2 = (a_1 \lambda _1)e_1 + (a_2 \lambda _2) e_2
$$
Since $a_1\lambda_1$ and $a_2 \lambda_2$ are just numbers, we can conclude from the above equation that $Ax$ is an element of $V$.

---

Indeed, as you say, $Ape_1$ is not a scalar multiple of $e_1$.  So, what you had done was not sufficient to answer the question.

Comment: (+1) OHHH I see :D Thank you very very much :) and thank you so much for bearing my nuisance :/ I really appreciate your help. Thank you so much again.

Comment: This is like the best answer imaginable :) Thank you so much. You can't imagine how happy I am :D

Comment: @TheArtist sorry if I gave you a bit of a hard time. Unfortunately, one of the bigger obstacles to learning mathematics is learning to ask questions in a way that allows others to see exactly what it is that you don't understand. I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: No no :) Even the part of telling me to change the question made me realize with confusion as to what parts are really important in this question, which in itself broadened my understanding. Add that to your excellent answer, it came out perfectly, now I understand the insufficient details of my first question as well as how to prove this :)

Comment: At the start of the question, I did not know how to prove. And also, I didn't know the importance of the other details, I put on the question the information that I thought was all that was needed to answer. So yes :) you corrected both my proof and why those missing details are important :) ...so don't say sorry :)